# Error when attempting distance() with raster

Tags: r, gis, spatial, raster

I have been trying to get a graph from using `distance()` in the `raster` package. The raster dimensions are inherited from a `SpatialPointsDataFrame`. The raster works fine until I try `distance(raster)` and get the following warning:

```
Warning message:

In matrix(v, ncol = tr$nrows[1] + 3) :
data length [8837790] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [4384]
```

The bizarre thing is the raster works at smaller resolution but not large. The error can be replicated below:

Fails:

```
library(raster)

r <- raster(ncol=4386,nrow=6039)
r[] <- NA
r[500] <- 1
dist <- distance(r)
plot(dist / 1000)
```

Works:

```
r <- raster(ncol=438.6,nrow=603.9)
r[] <- NA
r[500] <- 1
dist <- distance(r)
plot(dist / 1000)
```

Why? Have I missed something really obvious?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. I am using R `3.2.2` and `raster` version `2.4-22`.

Comment: What is your `sessinInfo()`?

Comment: works for me too, with the same specs as Pascal

Comment: Here is my sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] raster_2.1-49 sp_1.0-13    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_3.1.2      lattice_0.20-29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update to raster_2.4-20 solved the problem. Thanks Pascal and RobertH for pointing me in the right direction.